# How do I get the correct permissions to run 'mysqld --upgrade=FORCE'?

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-8.0

I'm attempting to run MySQL 8.0.30 on Ubuntu 22.04.

I'm trying to run the command `mysqld --upgrade=FORCE` as suggested in the answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54292491/7886407).  I can't tell if I'm doing it wrong or if there are other issues.

I have tried the four forms

1. `$ mysqld --upgrade=FORCE`
2. `$ sudo mysqld --upgrade=FORCE`
3. `$ mysqld --user=root --upgrade=FORCE`
4. `$ sudo mysqld --user=root --upgrade=FORCE`

The only one that even comes close to working is 4).  However, it changes the ownership of my `binlog` files in `/var/lib/mysql/` from `mysql:mysql` to `root:root`, as you can see in the following sample:

```
$ sudo ls /var/lib/mysql/
...
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  201 Sep 10 08:25  binlog.000015
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  201 Sep 11 09:12  binlog.000016
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  180 Sep 11 10:28  binlog.000017
-rw-r----- 1 root  root   180 Sep 11 10:42  binlog.000018
-rw-r----- 1 root  root   157 Sep 11 11:12  binlog.000019
-rw-r----- 1 root  root   304 Sep 11 11:12  binlog.index
...
```

10:42 is when I first ran the command `sudo mysqld --user=root --upgrade=FORCE`.  This, in turn, throws the error

```
Sep 11 11:58:50 System mysqld[72100]: mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

when I try to start the MySQL server with `$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service`.  Thus, I can conclude that the form 4) `$ sudo mysqld --user=root --upgrade=FORCE` is not the correct way to issue this command, else it wouldn't cause such an error.

**Please do not respond to suggest changing ownership of these files.  That isn't the point.**

I assume that the undesired change in ownership of the `binlog` files is due to running the command with `sudo`.  This narrows down the correct forms to either 1) or 3).  However, when I run either of those, I get the following error from running the command:

```
2022-09-11T18:27:19.993999Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
```

This is a common error, but none of the common causes for it seem to apply to my case.

The permissions on the data directory `/var/lib/mysql/` are exactly as they're supposed to be, as far as I can tell:

```bash
$ ls -d /var/lib/
drwxr-xr-x 79 root root 4.0K Aug 31 19:50 /var/lib/

$ ls -d /var/lib/mysql
drwx------ 7 mysql mysql 4.0K Sep 11 11:58 /var/lib/mysql
```

These are exactly the same as on a different system that functions perfectly well, and they agree with what the consensus on the Internet says these are supposed to be.  This is the standard MySQL data directory on Ubuntu, and I haven't tampered with it since installation.

This also is not an AppArmor issue, which is a common cause of this error.  My AppArmor config for MySQL, `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`, has the following config within the `/usr/sbin/mysqld {}` block:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld {

  ...
  
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,

  ...
}
```

which should be sufficient to cover this case.  As an extra check, I stopped AppArmor with `$ sudo systemctl stop apparmor.service`, ran commands 1) and 3) again, and got the same result.

What is the root cause of the permissions error when I run `$ mysqld --upgrade=FORCE`, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I have, in fact you'll note that both forms 3) and 4) use that very syntax.